# Cached mysql inserts - Preserving Data integrity

Tags: php, mysql, caching, insert, bulk

I would like to do a lot of inserts, but could it be possible to update mysql after a while.

For example if there is a query such as

```
Update views_table SET views = views + 1 WHERE id = 12;
```

Could it not be possible to maybe store this query until the views have gone up to 100 and then run the following instead of running the query from above 100 times.

```
Update views_table SET views = views + 100 WHERE id = 12;
```

Now, lets say that is done, then comes the problem of data integrity. Let's say, there are 100 php files open which are all about to run the same query. Now unless there is a locking mechanism on incrementing the cached views, there is a possibility that multiple files may have a same value of the cached view, so lets say process 1 may have 25 cached views and php process 2 may have 25 views and process 3 may have 27 views from the file. Now lets say process 3 finishes and increments the counter to 28. Then lets say php process is about finish and it finished just after process 3, which means that the counter would be brought back down to 26.

So do you guys have any solutions that are fast but are data secure as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your queries use **relative** values `views=views+5`, there should be **no problems**.

Only if you store the value somewhere in your script, and then calculate the new value yourself,you might run into trouble. But why would you want to do this? Actually, **why do you want to do all of this** in the first place? :)

If you don't want to overload the database, you could use `UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY table set ...`, the [`LOW_PRIORITY` keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) will put the update action in a queue and wait for the table to no longer be used by reads or inserts.

Comment: Good answer, but just to clarify: a `LOW_PRIORITY` query will still 'hang' until it can run (giving time to reads & inserts indeed, but not to the current process), it is explictly NOT the same as `INSERT DELAYED` for instance (which cannot be used here, but *does*  put the INSERT in a queue and will let you go on your merry way). The queue talked about here in with regards to `LOW_PRIORITY` is of processes already 'waiting to get access'.

Comment: oh ok, thats great...What about situations if there are several thousand updates per second

Answer (score 0):

First of all: with these queries: regardless of when a process starts, the `UPDATE .. SET col = col + 1` is a safe operation, so it will not 'decrease' the counter, ever.

Regarding to '*store this query until the views have gone up to 100 and then run the following instead of running the query from above 100 times*': not really. You can store a counter in faster memory (memcached comes to mind), with a process that transfers it to the database once in a while, or store it in another table with a `AFTER UPDATE` trigger, but I don't really see a point doing that.

Comment: so do you advice running the query a 100 times

Comment: A 100 times per week? Per day? Per minute?

Comment: If you really need to run it a LOT of times and your DB can't keep up, you might consider using something like memcached to store the variable, and only updating the database every X times - but as long as there are no problems, don't start optimizing prematurely.

Comment: I would advise parsing access_logs the web server has made at your leisure if you don't need to have realtime data. Choose a moment your server is doing little anyway (in the middle of the night perhaps, but it may depend on the site itself) to parse the logs, update the corresponding view counts, and be done with it. Zero overhead on your normal pageloads, updating at your leisure.